# Верхняя панель в Chrome? (закладки, панель поиска и тп)

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, responsive

Ребята, такая штука попалась...
Есть

```
.big_background {
  width: 110%;
  height: 110vh;
  min-height: 110vh;
  background-image: url("../img/big_gb.jpg");
  background-position: center -10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Проблема только в мобильных Хромах... 
При скроле верхняя панелька пропадает (особенность хрома наверно), и соответственно меняется высота экрана (я так понимаю) и картинка прыгает... 
Что можно придумать, чтобы это пофиксить?
Или как-то с картинкой поступить или с этой панелькой... НО! фон должен быть фиксирован, а текст кататься...

ЗЫ. https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php Как пример

Comment: А нельзя картинку по нижнему краю экрана выровнять, чтобы она при изменении размера экрана росла вверх?..

Comment: Не, все ровно полоса появляется

Comment: Если сделать ничего нельзя, напишите плз... начальство требует... А я не знаю (